# Set initial position for vtkOrientationMarkerWidget after camera rotation

Tags: image, rotation, vtk

I have embedded the vtkOrientationMarkerWidget to a viewer to indicate the orientation of an image volume. The viewer allows interactive rotation of the camera and displays the image volume accordingly while the widget is updated as the camera rotates. Normally the widget orientation would work perfectly fine, but for case of oblique image volume, where the initial orientation needs to be adjusted, the widget's initial position would become rotated and no longer matches the standard orientation of image. Currently, I have adjusted the initial orientation of the image volume by rotating the camera using vtkCamera's ApplyTransform function. I would like the widget to stay unrotated during this rotation. Are there ways to accomplish this?

I have tried rotating the orientation marker by itself, but with no avails. The widget orientation is tied to the camera and there seems to be no way of adjusting the rotation of the widget.